# Adding Tables to a Minipage Like Environment?

Tags: environments, minipage, examples

I'm trying to set up an environment to use for examples in my thesis document.  I would like to increase margins, change the line spacing, open with "Example :", and close with $\Box$.  Minipage works beautifully except I can't embed tables or figures within my examples.

This is what I have:

```
\newcounter{examplecounter}
\newenvironment{example}
{
\vspace{1.75em}
\begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}[h]{0.85\textwidth}
        \setlength{\parindent}{2em}
        \refstepcounter{examplecounter}
        \begin{oneandahalfspaced}
        \noindent
        \textbf{Example \arabic{examplecounter}:}
        }{
        \hspace{-1em}
        $\Box$
        \end{oneandahalfspaced}
    \end{minipage}
\end{center}
\vspace{1.75em}
}
```

Any suggestions on how to accomplish what I'm looking for?

Comment: I tip about including other environments in `\newenvironment` s: Instead of e.g. `\begin{center}` ... `\end{center}` you can write `\center` ... `\endcenter`. This has the advantage that if the `\end{example}` is misplaced you get a proper warning, otherwise the name of most inner environment started with `\begin{` will be printed, here: `! LaTeX Error: \begin{oneandahalfspaced} on input line XX ended by ...` and people get confused because the never typed that environment by themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have a `figure` environment inside a `minipage` because its a *float*, same counts for `table`. However you can include an image using `\includegraphics` (`graphicx` package) and also add a caption using the `capt-of` package: `\captionof{figuree}{<the caption text>}`.

See also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10394/using-an-image-as-a-table/10396#10396) which explains *float* environments vs. their content as well.

Comment: Martin, thanks for the quick answer and the reference.  After reading the link I was able to get my table (minus the caption and reference label) using \begin{tabular}