# How to force table caption on top?

Tags: tables, floats, positioning, captions

I have a table which works ok...as per example below. But in the thesis, the right column is centered and caption forced to below table. Is there a way I can make it look like?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
\caption{Four months plan: where,what how}
\begin{tabular}{lclclclc}
\hline
\hline
Month & Week & Programme\\
\hline
May & 3-4 & Cycle Tour\\
June & 1-2 & DCP Project\\
July & 1-2 & Clean Energy\\
August & 3-4 & Interim Report\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

There are multiple ways to force a table caption on top of the tables.

---

You could use the `float` package and use the following code:

```
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
```

A *drawback* of this is that you can't have more than one caption per `table`, i.e. you can't have two different `tabular`s with two captions side-by-side.

If your table caption are already forced to be below the table (normally they are placed where the `\caption` macro is used), some part of your thesis, maybe a custom package, might already use `float` with different settings.

---

You can also set the table caption position to the top using:

```
\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
```

However, this should only influence the vertical skip around the caption. Without this line the caption in your example should be already placed on top, just not with the correct distance.

---

Finally you can define a `\captionabove` macro and place this at the begin of the `table` environment. This macro uses the normal `\caption` but uses the correct vertical spacing for top-captions (by compensating the spacing added by `\caption` and adding the correct one).

(It would also be possible to swap the values of the `\abovecaptionskip` and `\belowcaptionskip` registers, but this requires grouping which has a negative impact on a `\label` which follows.)

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\captionabove}[2][]{%
    \vskip-\abovecaptionskip
    \vskip+\belowcaptionskip
    \ifx\@nnil#1\@nnil
        \caption{#2}%
    \else
        \caption[#1]{#2}%
    \fi
    \vskip+\abovecaptionskip
    \vskip-\belowcaptionskip
}

% If \captionof is required:
% Usage: \captionaboveof[<short caption>]{table}{<caption>}
\newcommand{\captionaboveof}[3][]{%
    \vskip-\abovecaptionskip
    \vskip+\belowcaptionskip
    \def\@captype{#2}%
    \ifx\@nnil#1\@nnil
        \caption{#3}%
    \else
        \caption[#1]{#3}%
    \fi
    \vskip+\abovecaptionskip
    \vskip-\belowcaptionskip
}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 39):

Even with the `\caption` command placed after the `tabular` environment, you may force the caption on top of the table by using the [`floatrow`](http://ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) package and its `\floatsetup` macro.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
\begin{tabular}{lclclclc}
\hline
\hline
Month & Week & Programme\\
\hline
May & 3-4 & Cycle Tour\\
June & 1-2 & DCP Project\\
July & 1-2 & Clean Energy\\
August & 3-4 & Interim Report\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Four months plan: where,what how}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your unswer seems to work well, but doesn't work on tabulars place inside a `floatbox` environment. I use floatboxes to place tables next to figures. Any sugestions?

Answer (score 12):

The location of the caption is traditionally underneath the float. However, it is up to you to therefore insert the caption command after the actual contents of the float (but still within the environment). If you place it before, then the caption will appear above the float.
example:

```
\begin{figure}
  \caption{A picture of a tucan.}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics{tucan.eps}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Source: http://www.andy-roberts.net/writing/latex/floats_figures_captions

Comment: What if I'm using captionof? because I need to use it with minted.

Comment: @skan also works with `\captionof`! +1 for this simple solution, not needing additional packages.

Answer (score 1):

Just write above the tabular group

```
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Some caption}
  \begin{tabular}{l l}
    test & jahkh \\
    kkjhj & asçlkd
  \end{tabular}
  \label{tab:teste}
\end{table}
```