# Table reference

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

I wrote a long table with a label in a tex file and `\input` it into my main tex file. The reference in the main tex file to the table, however, does not show the numbering of the table but the one of the next table that are written directly in the main tex file. All long tables that are written directly in the main tex file have correct references. How to fix my problem? Must the label be defined in the same tex file as its reference?

The label is `\label{tab:yy}`, and the reference is `\ref{tab:yy}`, and every table has a distinct label.

Comment: If you have not already done so, check for spelling and coping errors in the `\label`'s. Also for duplicate `\label`s. I've been stymied by that kind of thing once or twice.

Comment: The label is \label{tab:yy}, and the reference is \ref{tab:yy}, and every table has a distinct label.

Comment: I had the same error! Unless I moved the label inside the caption, I was getting all kinds of wacky errors on the referenced tables and figures! Thank goodness I found this conversation!!! SO: moral of the story, just put the \label{uniquelabelhere} inside the caption affiliated with the intended referenced figure or table!

Comment: One of the stupidities of LaTeX. I never understood why, but as a matter of fact you have to put the caption above the label, e.g. \caption{Picture} \label{pic} otherwise LaTeX will get it wrong.

Comment: The `\label` macro always labels the last thing which increased a counter. If you put it before `\caption` you are labeling usually the last sectioning command. This makes perfectly sense and is not a stupidity.  This fact is also usually mentioned in many beginner texts about LaTeX.

Comment: @MartinScharrer not only is it described in beginner texts, the problem was one of my targets when i was developing the uk tex faq in 1994.  unfortunately, as i've discussed on `meta`, nobody actually reads the faq now, despite my nearly 20 years of development work on it.  :-(

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This may or may not help, but I've had similar problems with figure references where the figure number inserted into the text in place of the `\ref` command was wrong. I managed to solve it by putting the `\label` inside the figure's `\caption`, viz:

```
\begin{figure}
\caption{Some caption.\label{fig:some-figure}}
\includegraphics{some-figure.eps}
\end{figure}
```

It's difficult to say more without a more extensive example of what's going wrong, though!

Comment: Thanks! It works. I put \label just before \end when it did not work. Why is this?

Comment: @Tim: I'm not entirely sure! If anyone else could answer this I'd be interested to hear.

Comment: I think it has something to do with when the counter is generated, see this answer:
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23385/table-numbering-mismatch-in-caption-and-in-text

Answer (score 7):

In my case I solved it by writing `\caption` and `\label` together.

```
\caption{Test table}
\label{tb:testTable}
```

Comment: @random: Your edit made it worse instead of better. In LaTeX-code shouldn't be any HTML tags.

Comment: That's what you get for kludging through and not using the toolbar by hacking in HTML tags to display code. @pau

Comment: Did do the trick for me, so the order is important.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you need to rerun (La)TeX in order to imbed the new .aux file with the updated references?

---

OK, not that.

Could you post a minimal example that fails?

---

Sorry, don't know why @Will's answer works. Neither of my two bibles (the [memoir manual](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) and the [Guide to LaTeX2e](http://www.bluesky.com/bookshelf/guidetolatex/gl.html)) says anything. The examples from there show `\label{}` coming right after `\caption{}`, not inside it.

???

Comment: Thanks! But no matter how many times latex command is run, the numbering is still wrong.

Comment: See the answer of Will. Do you know why?

Answer (score -1):

I am using memoir and I learnt that the label has always to go after the caption.

Comment: It can also be in the caption command `\caption{\label{tab:yy} here is the caption}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.