# More than one table per subsubsection is referred to by section number

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, captions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Table reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28422/table-reference)
>   [Why does an environment's label have to appear after the caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32325/why-does-an-environments-label-have-to-appear-after-the-caption)

If you compile the LaTeX below, you get section numbers for some references instead of table numbers. This happens after the first two.

Code to reproduce:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\subsubsection{Example}
\label{sec-2-4-1}
    (see tables \ref{doc-1} and \ref{doc-2})
\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{document 1} 
\label{doc-1}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{llr}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{document 2} 
  \label{doc-2}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{llr}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
    (see table \ref{doc-extracted}).
\begin{table}[htb]
  \label{doc-extracted}
\caption{extracted} 
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{llr}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
    (see table \ref{doc-sum})
    (see table \ref{doc-avg}).
\begin{table}[htb]
  \label{doc-sum}
\caption{sum} 
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[htb]
  \label{doc-avg}
\caption{average} 
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Would anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Always put captions before labels.

Comment: Inside a float, `\label` must always go **after** `\caption`.

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. The first one to answer gets +15 :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always put captions before labels.