# How to highlight only some cell in table

Tags: tables, color

Can anybody help to highlight some specific cell in table. I tried it but getting error that undefined sequence. Thank you in advance

```
\documentclass[12pt,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[hbt]
\centering
\captionabove{Initial assumed values}
\begin{tabular}{|p{3.5cm}|p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}| p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}| p{0.5cm}| p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}| p{0.5cm}| p{0.5cm}| p{0.5cm}|p{0.5cm}| }\hline
Parameter            & 80   & 84  & 88   & 92  & 93   & 96   & 100 & 104   & 108   & 112  & 116 \\\hline
Cellular bacteria(\%)      & \cellcolor{blue!25}$86.5$   & $62.5$   & $56.3$   & $37.5$   & $50$   & $50$   & $37.5$ & \cellcolor{blue!25}$87.5$   & $37.5$  & \cellcolor{blue!25}$75 $ & $66.7$  \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\captionabove` is a KOMA-script specific command. It thus does not work (and results in an undefined control sequence error) when used in stardard document classes. You might want to replace `\documentclass{article}` with `\documentclass{scrartcl}` or stay with `article` and use `\caption{Initial assumed values}` instead.

Comment: ... or copy the definition of `\captionabove` from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22754.

Comment: Additionally to the error message, you will get a ton or overfull box warnings. You might also want to take care of them. Also the vertical lines in your header row are discontinuous due to you adding an empty line by using `\\\\ ` Lastly, your table is a lot wider than the textwidth of a standard `article` class document, even with smaller column widths.

Comment: my document class i updated above. \documentclass[12pt,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl} even though undefined sequence

Comment: @maths: Sorry, but with the updated example, I get no error messages at all, just warnings and the flaws in the output that I already mentioned in my previous comment. Therefore please tell us which control sequence is undefined. Your log file should contain this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I could  not reproduce any "undefined control sequence"  error message with the updated example code, I focused on the flaws in the output. Here are therefore 4 different tables using different font sizes ans alignments while keeping the original style of the table unchanged:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[hbt]
\centering
\captionabove{Initial assumed values - smaller font size, tabularx, equal column widths}
\small \setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|*{11}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\widthof{99.9}}|}}\hline
Parameter            & {80}   & {84}  & {88}   & {92}  & {93}   & {96}   & {100} & {104}   & {108}   & {112}  & {116} \\ \hline\hline
Cellular bacteria(\%)      & \cellcolor{blue!25}86.5   & 62.5   & 56.3   & 37.5   & 50   & 50   & 37.5 & \cellcolor{blue!25}87.5   & 37.5  & \cellcolor{blue!25}75  & 66.7 \\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[hbt]
\centering
\captionabove{Initial assumed values - normal font size, tabularx, equal column width, vertically centered numbers}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X|*{11}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\widthof{99.9}}|}}\hline
Parameter            & {80}   & {84}  & {88}   & {92}  & {93}   & {96}   & {100} & {104}   & {108}   & {112}  & {116} \\ \hline\hline
Cellular bacteria(\%)      & \cellcolor{blue!25}86.5   & 62.5   & 56.3   & 37.5   & 50   & 50   & 37.5 & \cellcolor{blue!25}87.5   & 37.5  & \cellcolor{blue!25}75  & 66.7 \\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[hbt]
\centering
\captionabove{Initial assumed values - normal font size, unequal column widths, tabularx}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X|*{11}{c|}}\hline
Parameter            & {80}   & {84}  & {88}   & {92}  & {93}   & {96}   & {100} & {104}   & {108}   & {112}  & {116} \\ \hline\hline
Cellular bacteria(\%)      & \cellcolor{blue!25}86.5   & 62.5   & 56.3   & 37.5   & 50   & 50   & 37.5 & \cellcolor{blue!25}87.5   & 37.5  & \cellcolor{blue!25}75  & 66.7 \\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[hbt]
\centering
\captionabove{Initial assumed values - normal font size, tabularx, equal column widths, alignment of numbers with siunitx}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X|*{11}{S[table-format=2.1]|}}\hline
Parameter            & {80}   & {84}  & {88}   & {92}  & {93}   & {96}   & {100} & {104}   & {108}   & {112}  & {116} \\ \hline\hline
Cellular bacteria(\%)      & \cellcolor{blue!25}86.5   & 62.5   & 56.3   & 37.5   & 50   & 50   & 37.5 & \cellcolor{blue!25}87.5   & 37.5  & \cellcolor{blue!25}75  & 66.7 \\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Here is also another suggestion on how you could design your table based on `booktabs` and without the use of color:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\bfseries
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[hbt]
\centering
\captionabove{Initial assumed values - normal font size, tabularx, equal column widths, alignment of numbers with siunitx, no vertical lines, horizontal lines from booktabs, no color but bold instead to highlight numbers}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X*{11}{S[table-format=2.1,detect-weight]}}
\toprule
Parameter            & {80}   & {84}  & {88}   & {92}  & {93}   & {96}   & {100} & {104}   & {108}   & {112}  & {116} \\ 
\midrule
Cellular bacteria(\%)      & \bfseries 86.5   & 62.5   & 56.3   & 37.5   & 50   & 50   & 37.5 & \bfseries 87.5   & 37.5  & \bfseries 75  & 66.7 \\
Cellular bacteria(\%)      & 86   & 62.5   & 56.3   & 37.5   & 50.5   & 50.2   & 37.5 & 87.5   & 37.5  & 75  & 66.7 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very very much