# Overriding caption placement defined by document class

Tags: tables, captions, document-classes

I'm using the `FrontiersinHavard` Latex class provided by the [author guidelines of the Frontiers Media](https://www.frontiersin.org/guidelines/author-guidelines). Strangely enough, even though their guidelines specifically state table captions should be placed *above* the table, the class forces the captions under the tables.
There is also little to no documentation on that document class itself.

Are there any options to disable this behavior when declaring the document class, or does one need some other [workaround](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22751/how-to-force-table-caption-on-top) to override the document class?

Comment: I can't confirm your claim that the caption is below. In any case: if they class doesn't do what it should do, complain to the author.