# Add figure, which is a table, to the list of tables

Tags: tables, graphics, table-of-contents, thesis

I am converting my thesis from Word to LaTeX, and I saved several huge tables as images.

For my thesis I have to compile a list of tables and figures. I am using `\listoftables` and `\listoffigures`.

However, now that some of my tables are given by images, it would add those table to the List of Figures. What would be a good way to list those images to the List of Tables as well (instead of List of Figures).

I could imagine there should be a way to make an invisible table with one cell which contains the table image. Maybe somebody has LaTeX code.

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: See also [Using an image as a table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10394).

Answer (score 15):

You can simply go

```
\begin{table}
    \includegraphics{....
```

there is no requirement to use `tabular` in `table` or to use `\includegraphics` in `figure`

The commenters requested code to put the caption in *both* the lof and the lot, so in cse that is what you meant:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\listoffigures

\section{jkhgfv}

\begin{table}[h]
 table
\caption[my (lot) table]{my table}
  \addcontentsline{lof}{table}%
    {\protect\numberline\thetable\ignorespaces my (lof) table}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 could you mention how to add it to the `listoffigures`?

Comment: well you could, but I thought the question was to not make it appear there and appear in list of tables (and actually, perhaps more important) keep in sequence with tables.

Comment: To dodge all uncertainties, you could just add a complete example at the end, with a LoT as well as a LoF (but keep the "abstract" solution at the top for itself).

Comment: @doncherry,  code to duplicate caption in lof and lot, as requested

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Sorry, I was being unclear -- I actually meant a MWE showing what the OP requested, _plus_ a LoF, naturally _not_ listing the table, just to show that it isn't influenced by the picture-table.