# Table of images with captions

Tags: tables, floats

I have a table with four images.

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{table caption...}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[width=45mm]{w.png} &\includegraphics[width=45mm]{x.png}\\
\newline
\includegraphics[width=45mm]{y.png}&\includegraphics[width=45mm]{z.png}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I want to caption each of the images. Normally I would do this by placing `includegraphics` within a `\begin{figure}` block using `\caption{...}`. But when I do this, the images disappear.

What is the proper way to do this, so that I can caption each of the images.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Or you could use the `subfig` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[Caption 1]{
        \label{ref_label1}
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    }
    \subfloat[Caption 2]{
        \label{ref_label2}
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    }
    \caption{Overall caption}
    \label{ref_label_overall}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What if i want to add 4 images in two rows, how can i mdify this code?

Comment: \hfill is suggested between two subfloats to have them seperated

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`subcaption`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/subcaption) package for this but I think you don't need table for such use. You can embed everything into a general figure environment and place them as you wish. See the manual for that. Here is the version with Table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe} % For dummy images
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
{\centering
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}\centering\includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth]{example-image-a}\caption{Figure A}\label{fig:taba}\end{subfigure}&
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}\centering\includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth]{example-image-b}\caption{Figure B}\label{fig:tabb}\end{subfigure}\\
\newline
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}\centering\includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth]{example-image-c}\caption{Figure C}\label{fig:tabc}\end{subfigure}&
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}\centering\includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth]{example-image-a}\caption{Figure A again}\label{fig:taba2}\end{subfigure}\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{A table with figures}
\label{tab:mytable}
\end{table}
}

We can see that Figure \ref{fig:taba} and Figure \ref{fig:taba2} is the same. Also the table counter value is used for the reference.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do you control the vertical distance between the rows of figures?

Answer (score 4):

You could simply use `capt-of` which provides stand-alone `captionof` command

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Simple but not clever}
\centering
\begin{tabu}to \textwidth {X[c]X[c]}
  \includegraphics[width=45mm]{w.png}\captionof{figure}{fd} &\includegraphics[width=45mm]{x.png}\captionof{figure}{fd} \\
  \includegraphics[width=45mm]{y.png}\captionof{figure}{fd} &\includegraphics[width=45mm]{z.png}\captionof{figure}{fd} \\
\end{tabu}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This has two disadvantages: first it's not elegant and the table caption is much to close to the first picture. In my opinion one of the `subfig` or `subcaption`  solutions is much better. When using a `KOMA` class there is no need to load `capt-of`.

Answer (score 2):

Building off of a previous answer, if you want to use the subfig package with multiple rows:

```
\usepackage{subfig}

...

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfloat[Caption 1]{\label{ref_label1}\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{path/to/figure1}}
  \subfloat[Caption 2]{\label{ref_label2}\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{path/to/figure1}}
  % leave a blank space for a new row

  \subfloat[Caption 3]{\label{ref_label3}\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{path/to/figure3}}
  \subfloat[Caption 4]{\label{ref_label4}\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{path/to/figure4}}
  \caption{\label{ref_label_overall}Overall caption}
\end{figure}
```