# !Misplaced \omit. \multispan -> \omit for stacked image figure

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I am trying to create a figure composed of 2 images stacked vertically, with captions underneath each.  There are 2 captions (horizontally) under the second image, therefore I use 2 columns.  My latex is the following:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}l@{}}
\begin{multicolumn}{2}{c}{\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{fig_a.png}} \\
\begin{multicolumn}{2}{p{0.8\linewidth}}{Caption (a)}  \\
\begin{multicolumn}{2}{l}{\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{fig_b_c.png}}\\
\begin{multicolumn}{1}{r}{Caption (b)} &
\begin{multicolumn}{1}{r}{(Caption (c)}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Figure caption.}
\label{fig:two-part-image} 
\end{figure}
```

However I am getting the error

```
!Misplaced \omit.
\multispan ->\omit
@\multispan
```

and can't figure out what is wrong.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: might i sugggest you have a look at `subfigure` or `subcaption` or anything other than a table inside of a figure?  a quick search brings up [these answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64038/960) which do that, and i'm sure there are more on this site.

Comment: Don't use `\begin{multicolumn}`... instead `\multicolumn{..}{..}{...}`.

Comment: @Werner You gave the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `\begin{multicolumn}`... instead use `\multicolumn{<num>}{<col spec>}{<stuff>}`. This will make a single cell entry with `<stuff>` span `<num>` columns with `<col spec>` as a specification (like `c` or `p{<len>}`).