# Using Word table as a LaTeX table

Tags: tables, graphics, floats, msword

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using an image as a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10394/using-an-image-as-a-table)

Assume that I created a table in Microsoft Word. I can save it as eps, pdf, etc. and use it in LaTeX. However, the caption is "Figure X". Is there a way to change this to "Table X"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the included figure in the `table` environment:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[..]{...}
  \caption[<LoT entry>]{<Regular caption>}
\end{table}
```

`table`, just like `figure` is merely a floating placeholder and can contain anything.